# Array of a generic type in lambda function declaration not compiling

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a generic function, which receives a callback function, one of whose parameters is an array of that generic type. The method is declared as:

```
private addPossibleIncludedItems<T extends HasId>(
            jsonApiResponse: any,
            objectList: ObjectTO[],
            typeString: TypeString,
            relationshipIdsGetter: (ObjectTO) => string[],
            multipleItemSetter: (ObjectTO, T[]) => void,
                  // compilation error here ^
            conversionCallBack: (any) => T) {
...
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
[ts] ',' expected. [1005]
```

I can't seem to find any reason for this error, as I've seen declarations with generic types being used as an array parameter declaration, so I'm quite stumped. Why doesn't my method declaration compile?

EDIT: The one without the array type compiles just fine:

```
private addPossibleIncludedItem<T extends HasId>(
            jsonApiResponse: any,
            objectList: ObjectTO[],
            typeString: TypeString,
            relationshipIdGetter: (ObjectTO) => string,
            singleItemSetter: (ObjectTO, T) => void,
            conversionCallBack: (any) => T) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Name your parameters before you give them types:

```
multipleItemSetter: (a: ObjectTO, b: T[]) => void,
```

This also applies to:

```
relationshipIdsGetter: (nameMe: ObjectTO) => string[],
```

... and ...

```
conversionCallBack: (nameMe: any) => T)
```

Full example:

```
private addPossibleIncludedItems<T extends HasId>(
    jsonApiResponse: any,
    objectList: ObjectTO[],
    typeString: TypeString,
    relationshipIdsGetter: (nameMe: ObjectTO) => string[],
    multipleItemSetter: (a: ObjectTO, b: T[]) => void,
    conversionCallBack: (nameMe: any) => T) {
}
```